# Navigating XML to access CDATA using XML::TWIG

Tags: xml, perl, xml-twig

I have this XML file and I need to access specific nodes one at a time. Below is a sample of my XML along with my sample code.

My code is working fine except that I loop through all of the Message/Content tags instead of just getting the specific Message/Content tag under the current Message tag. For example, I would get back 3 Message/Content tags when the current Message tag is being processed (the one with refid="123991123") when I only want 1 returned (). Hope this is making sense. Any help here would be appreciated.

Code:

```
my $twig = XML::Twig->new(
twig_handlers => {
    Selection => sub {
        foreach my $message ($_->findnodes('./Contents/Message')) {

            if($message->att('custom')){
                $Message_custom = $message->att('custom');
                foreach my $Content ($_->findnodes('./Contents/Message/Content')) {
                    print $Selection_id.": ".$Message_refid.": ".$TotalContents++."\n";
                    if($Content->att('language') eq "en"){
                        if($Content->att('imagelibraryid')){
                            $Message_Content_language_en_imagelibraryid = $Content->att('imagelibraryid');
                        }else{
                            $Message_Content_language_en = substr($message->field('Content'), 0, 20);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    },
}
);
```

XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Root>
  <Selection id="54008473">
    <Name>Master</Name>
    <Contents>
      <Message refid="125796458" suppress="true" status="Unchanged"/>
      <Message refid="123991123" suppress="true" status="Unchanged">
        <Content language="en" imagelibraryid="5492396"/>
      </Message>
      <Message refid="128054778" custom="true" status="New">
        <Content language="en"><![CDATA[<p>Some English content</p>]]></Content>
        <Content language="fr"><![CDATA[<p>Some French content</p>]]></Content>
      </Message>
    </Contents>
  </Selection>
  <Selection id="54008475" datavaluerefid="54008479">
    <Name>RMBC</Name>
    <Contents>
      <Message refid="125796458" sameasparent="true" parentrefid="54008473" status="Unchanged"/>
      <Message refid="123991123" sameasparent="true" parentrefid="54008473" status="Unchanged"/>
      <Message refid="128054778" custom="true" status="New">
        <Content language="en"><![CDATA[<p>ada</p>]]></Content>
      </Message>
    </Contents>
  </Selection>
</Root>
```

Comment: your code does not compile under strict/warnings and `$Message_refid` is never set. Please fix this so it can be debugged.

Comment: I'm having a hard time understanding what you are trying to make your code do. What output are you trying to obtain?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a first attempt to try to understand what your code is supposed to do, based on the structure of the XML:

- handler for `Selection` nodes looks for children `Content` nodes  with attribute `language == 'en'` under `Message` nodes under `Content`nodes

  - translates to XPath `./Contents/Message/Content[@language='en']`
  - if it has an attribute `imagelibraryid`, store the value of that
  - otherwise store the `CDATA` content of the first child
  - set `refid` to the attribute value from parent `Message` node
- append them to the content list for the `Selection` node
- to show what was collected, use [Data::Dumper](https://metacpan.org/pod/Data::Dumper) on the array ref

```perl
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;

use XML::Twig;
use Data::Dumper;

my %selections;

my $twig = XML::Twig->new(
    twig_handlers => {
        Selection => sub {
            #$_->print();
            print "selection id: ", $_->att('id'), "\n";

            my @contents;
            foreach my $content ($_->findnodes("./Contents/Message/Content[\@language='en']")) {
                my $result = {
                    refid => $content->parent->att('refid'),
                };
                my $id     = $content->att('imagelibraryid');
                if (defined $id) {
                    $result->{library} = $id;
                } else {
                    $result->{cata}    = $content->first_child->cdata;
                }
                push(@contents, $result);
            }

            # store collected Content nodes under selection ID
            $selections{ $_->att('id') } = \@contents;
        },
    }
);

$twig->parse(\*DATA);

while (my($id, $contents) = each %selections) {
    my $dump = Dumper($contents);
    print "Selection '${id}' messages: $dump\n";
}

exit 0;

__DATA__
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
... the rest of your XML left out ...
```

Test run:

```
$ perl dummy.pl
selection id: 54008473
selection id: 54008475
Selection '54008473' messages: $VAR1 = [
          {
            'refid' => '123991123',
            'library' => '5492396'
          },
          {
            'cata' => '<p>Some English content</p>',
            'refid' => '128054778'
          }
        ];

Selection '54008475' messages: $VAR1 = [
          {
            'cata' => '<p>ada</p>',
            'refid' => '128054778'
          }
        ];
```

Comment: Updated answer with the `CDATA` instruction. I hope that is what you were looking for.

Comment: Hi Everyone, sorry for my unclear question. The sad part is...I thought it was clear.  I'll try to be more clear in the future.

With that said, Stefan, I think you're the only one that understands my language :). Don't know if that's good news or bad news. Anyway, your code was almost spot on. The only thing I added was [\@refid='$Message_refid'] to isolate only Content items under specific Message Nodes (see code below):

    foreach my $Content ($_->findnodes("./Contents/Message[\@refid='$Message_refid']/Content[\@language='en']")) {

Thank You! I've learned a lot from you.

Angelo